# Firefox shows inconsistent behavior with video 'progress' event

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-video

It seems that about half the time, Firefox 24 fails to call the progress event on my HTML5 video. A live demo can be seen here: https://mediacru.sh/Cjbft93YWNNu

I'm using h.264 for the video, and the server should be set up correctly for streaming. It works great on Chrome.

Comment: This link is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is pretty simple. The video is already fully loaded before you are adding the progress event. Also note, that you have to use 'timeupdate' instead of 'timeUpdate'.

You can write the following:

```
videos[i].addEventListener('progress', updateVideo, false);
//if video has already some data call updateVideo
if(videos[i].readyState > 0){
    updateVideo.call(videos[i], {target: videos[i]});
}
```

Comment: So the window.load event waits for the video to be fully loaded?

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood you. Looks like it's working well now, thanks!